# setting multiple keys/values into a dictionary (python 2.72)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a list of strings. I am willing to create a dictionary which its keys are all the strings in the list (each string is a key of course).

Now for the values: The value corresponding to each key will be the string which comes next after the key string on the list. The values will be from list type.

Remarks: The **last word won't be included in the dictionary**.
a key won't appear twice on the dic. if there are more than one values for a certain key, they will be added to the exist value's list of the key.
The order doesn't matter (the dictionary can be not sorted if it makes the job easier).

Example:

- for the list:

  ```
  List = ['today','is','worm','and','dry']
  ```
- the dictionary will be:

  ```
  Dic={'today': ['is'], 'is': ['worm'],'worm': ['and'], 'and':['dry']}
  ```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['today','is','worm','and','dry']

d = {}
for w1, w2 in zip(l, l[1:]):
    d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)

# d == {'and': ['dry'], 'is': ['worm'], 'today': ['is'], 'worm': ['and']}
```

Comment: Actually I believe `d = dict((w1, [w2]) for w1, w2 in zip(l, l[1:]))` is enough, as it will assign `{'and': ['dry'], 'is': ['worm'], 'worm': ['and'], 'today': ['is']}` to `d`.

Comment: @Tadeck - it will work for this case, but then the list does not make any sense, if you cannot assign more items to it.

Comment: You are wrong, the dictionary **is editable** as well as each **list is editable** within it. You can eg. do `d['and'].append('something')` and your `d` will be equal to `{'and': ['dry', 'something'], 'is': ['worm'], 'worm': ['and'], 'today': ['is']}`. It would be different if I would use tuples, but I did not. I really do not follow your reasoning - my code is shorter, solves the problem and does what you say it is not able to do. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = ['today','is','worm','and','dry']
dic = {}

for k in xrange(len(lst) - 1):
    dic[lst[k]] = [lst[k+1]]
```

It's an efficient answer, since it doesn't create any additional lists for building the dictionary. You can check the result, it's what was expected:

```
dic == {'today': ['is'], 'is': ['worm'],'worm': ['and'], 'and':['dry']}
> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very fine but it is working

```
>>> List = ['today','is','worm','and','dry']
>>> Dic ={}
>>> key = None
>>> for item in List:
...     if key:
...         Dic.update({key:item})
...     key=item
... 
>>> Dic
{'and': 'dry', 'is': 'worm', 'worm': 'and', 'today': 'is'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

(based on @eumiro's answer)

```
>>> l = ['today','is','worm','and','dry']
>>> print dict(zip(l, l[1:]))
{'and': 'dry', 'is': 'worm', 'worm': 'and', 'today': 'is'}
>>> print dict(zip(l, l[1:] + [None]))
{'and': 'dry', 'dry': None, 'is': 'worm', 'worm': 'and', 'today': 'is'}
>>> print dict((k, [v]) for (k, v) in zip(l, l[1:] + [None]))
{'and': ['dry'], 'dry': [None], 'is': ['worm'], 'worm': ['and'], 'today': ['is']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by the following code:

```
Dic = dict((key, [item]) for key, item in zip(List, List[1:]))
```

and the result will be the following:

```
>>> Dic
{'and': ['dry'], 'is': ['worm'], 'worm': ['and'], 'today': ['is']}
```

If you need more performant solution, you can **use `izip()` function**:

```
from itertools import izip
Dic = dict((key, [item]) for key, item in izip(List, List[1:]))
```

which will give the same result, but in a more efficient way.

But please **follow naming conventions for Python** (eg. call your variables `my_dict` and `my_list`, but preferably give them more meaningful names) and **do not overwrite `list` and `dict` keywords** (that is in case you would like to give your variables such names).